# Spring Boot fails loading AtomikosDataSourceBean

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, classloader, spring-tool-suite, atomikos

Spring Boot is not able to find an existing Atomikos dependency on startup:

```
    2019-12-12 09:09:35.836[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m2796[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'taskDatasourceConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'workFlowDataSource' defined in class path resource [cwp/services/adhoc_processor/config/NWFDatasourceConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'workFlowDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atomikos/jdbc/AtomikosDataSourceBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:400) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at cwp.services.adhoc_processor.Application.main(Application.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'workFlowDataSource' defined in class path resource [cwp/services/adhoc_processor/config/NWFDatasourceConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'workFlowDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atomikos/jdbc/AtomikosDataSourceBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'workFlowDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atomikos/jdbc/AtomikosDataSourceBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atomikos/jdbc/AtomikosDataSourceBean
    at cwp.services.adhoc_processor.config.NWFDatasourceConfiguration.workFlowDataSource(NWFDatasourceConfiguration.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at cwp.services.adhoc_processor.config.NWFDatasourceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$be6ffde1.CGLIB$workFlowDataSource$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at cwp.services.adhoc_processor.config.NWFDatasourceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$be6ffde1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2230db96.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at cwp.services.adhoc_processor.config.NWFDatasourceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$be6ffde1.workFlowDataSource(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

whereas it seems to properly exist on STS's classpath inside `transactions-jdbc-4.0.6.jar` pulled in as part of `spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos` dependency present in `pom.xml`:

[image]:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>xxxxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.9</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>cwp.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>xa-workflow-setup</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Payment Ad-Hoc Processor</name>
    <description>Payment Ad-Hoc Processor</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springboot.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</springboot.version>
        <spring-cloud-version>Greenwich.SR3</spring-cloud-version>
        <chaosmonkey.version>2.1.1</chaosmonkey.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- common domain objects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cwp.services</groupId>
            <artifactId>payment-orchestration-model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sbx.services</groupId>
            <artifactId>nxn-workflow-services</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Camunda-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>sbx.services</groupId>
                    <artifactId>api-security</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>
                        spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos
                    </artifactId>
                </exclusion>                
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sbx.services</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>chaos-monkey-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${chaosmonkey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here's also what Maven has in the local repo for both `atomikos` and s`pring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos`:

[image]

---

[image]

I'm inheriting the project from someone else, so I'm unsure as to the reason why it's needed but there's also exists the following extra class sitting next to the Boot's `Application.java`.  It doesn't seem to be called directly by anything in the application.

```
package cwp.services;

import javax.transaction.TransactionManager;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform;

public class AtomikosJtaPlatform extends AbstractJtaPlatform {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static TransactionManager transactionManager;
    static UserTransaction transaction;

    @Override
    protected TransactionManager locateTransactionManager() {
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected UserTransaction locateUserTransaction() {
        return transaction;
    }


    public static void setTransactionManager(TransactionManager transactionManager) {
        AtomikosJtaPlatform.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }


    public static void setTransaction(UserTransaction transaction) {
        AtomikosJtaPlatform.transaction = transaction;
    }
    
    

}
```

Here's also some seemingly relevant excerpts from the log of how Spring Boot resolves its dependencies on startup prior to that error:

```
AtomikosJtaConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)
```

How does Spring Boot detects a JTA environment?

Any pointers on how to resolve this STS/Atomikos class loading issue are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, can you try to delete atomikos from your local maven repo and launch things again?

Comment: @GuyPardon: that didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further examination, I discovered that the launch configuration for the project was misconfigured by pointing to another project which uses non-XA data source:

[image]

Pointing it to the current project seems to have fixed the issue.